# Node-addon-api - construct ObjectWrap from C++

Tags: c++, node.js, constructor, node-addon-api

I'm new to NAPI, and I'm trying to convert and old Nan code to NAPI.

What happens is that I have a structure like this:

```js
class PointWrapper : public Napi::ObjectWrap<PointWrapper> {
public:
  static void init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports);
  PointWrapper(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
private:
  Point point;
}
```

And I wrapped everything in the right way, so if I call on JS `new Pointer(1, 2)` it'll instantiate a `PointerWrapper` and set the right fields to `Point`. So far, so good.

Now, the problem is that somewhere later I have a C++ code that wraps a `Range` - a `Range` is basically `start` and `end`, each containing a `Point`.

I also have `RangeWrapper` that does the same thing as `PointWrapper`, but for range. This `RangeWrapper` have a `getStart` that basically needs to return a PointWrapper.

Now, how do I instantiate a `PointWrapper` from `RangeWrapper`? Basically, I want a constructor on `PointWrapper` that, giving a `Point`, I can get a `PointWrapper`, all this in C++ and not on JS. Is it possible? Every code I saw tried to instantiate from *inside* `PointWrapper`, never *outside*

Comment: Anyone found the solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution - it's clumsy, but at least it works. The first thing I had to do was to make the "constructor" a variable that other places could use. So I changed my class to have a `*constructor` pointer:

```cpp
class PointWrapper : public Napi::ObjectWrap<PointWrapper> {
public:
  static void init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports);
  PointWrapper(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
  static Napi::FunctionReference *constructor; // <-- Added this
private:
  Point point;
};
```

Then on my `init` implementation (file `point-wrapper.cpp`), I am using this constructor to "construct" the `Point`:

```cpp
Napi::FunctionReference *PointWrapper::constructor; // <-- Added this
void PointWrapper::init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  Napi::Function func = DefineClass(env, "Point", {
    // methods, etc...
  });

  constructor = new Napi::FunctionReference(); // <-- Used it here
  *constructor = Napi::Persistent(func); // <-- and here
  exports.Set("Point", func);
}
```

So, to instantiate the `PointWrapper` what I need is to call the constructor then unwrap things. Now, the class itself only have one possible constructor, that receives a `Napi::CallbackInfo& info`. To instantiate this class with something from C++ side, we need to "wrap" a C++ object into `Napi::External`:

```cpp
// Supposing you have a point already created:
auto wrapped = Napi::External<Point>::New(env, &Point);
Napi::Value pointWrapperAsVal = PointWrapper::constructor->New({ wrapped });
```

Finally, you make the controller understand that it can be called with a `Napi::External` object:

```cpp
PointWrapper::PointWrapper(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) 
                   : Napi::ObjectWrap<PointWrapper>(info) {
  if(info[0].IsExternal()) {
    auto point = info[0].As<Napi::External<Point>>();
    this->point = *point.Data();
  } else {
    // normal code
  }
}
```

Remember that `pointWrapperAsVal` is a `Napi::Value`. You may need to convert to the right "type" if you need to use it from CPP - for example, with `PointWrapper::Unwrap(pointWrapperAsVal)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been able to apply this to my use case (where I use a smart pointer for the c++ class) and it works properly, however I have a question, why there is not a Wrap method if there is an Unwrap one in Napi::ObjectWrap...